# How do i edit Login Required Page

Tags: mediawiki

On my private MediaWiki view & read is set to false.
My website visitors would see
Please Login to view other pages.
What needed to do was edit the login link located in this error message.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for this answer.
I finally found a Topic on MediaWiki Project:Support desk called
Editing "Login Required" Page.
It told me to
Try editing the page mediawiki:loginreqpagetext on your wiki
 ($1 is the link to special:userlogin using the title text at mediawiki:loginreqlink).

(Note: on newer mediawiki, you can see where the system messages come from by appending ?uselang=qqx to a url)

I changed the 
Please $1 to view other pages.
into
Please [https://www.example.com Login] to view other pages.